# React-native IOS [Network request Failed]

Tags: react-native, httprequest, xcode9

I'm new to react-native and I'm referring to "Learning React Native: Building Native Mobile Apps with JavaScript
Book by Bonnie Eisenman".

while working on one of the examples I encountered "network request failed" error,Application builds successfully but I get this error when application try to fetch the data from the server.

I tried every solution that is present on stack overflow related to this question but none of them resolved my issue.

IOS version is 11.3
MacOS version is 10.13.4
Xcode version is 9

**API code**

[image]

**info.plist**

[image]

**Error Image**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your `zipUrl` function, the `interpolation`/`template string` is used wrongly, you need to use back-tick (`) not single quote ('). Take a look at the document [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Please try by changing the return statement to

```
zipUrl(zip) {
  return `...`;
}
```

Hope this will help!

**Edit**:

I was able to get data by changing `http` to `https`.

Comment: Hi Prasun,

Thank you for your response but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Can you confirm whether the URL return by `zipUrl` is a valid one, I mean try to access the same using browser or postman.

Comment: Yes it is valid
I keyed " http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=10001&units=imperial&APPID=bbeb34ebf60ad50f7893e7440a1e2b0b " in browser and I'm getting response

Comment: What value you are getting in `console.log(error)` in catch statement, "Network request failed"?

Comment: Hi @Abhay, I just tried with `http` it show me error, but as soon as I changed to `https`, I go the data. Please try by changing `http` to `https`.

Comment: Changing Http to Https has resolved the issue.

Thanks buddy